# Hashing on multiple keys : for task execution In Multi threaded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, hashcode

I have certain objects on which certain tasks needs to be performed.On all objects all task needs to be performed. I want to employ multiple threads say N parallel threads

Say I have objects identifiers like A,B,C (Objects can be in 100 K range ; keys can be long or string)
And Tasks can T1,T2,T3,TN - (Task are max 20 in number)

Conditions for task execution -
Tasks can be executed in parallel even for the same object. 
But for the same object, for a given task, it should be executed in series.
Example , say I have 
Objects on which are task performed are A,B,A 
and tasks are t1, t2

So T1(A), T2(A) or T1(A) , T2(B) are possible , but T1(A) and T1(A) shouldnt be allowed

How can I ensure that , that my conditions are met. I know I have to use some sort of hashing.
I read about hashing , so my hash function can be of -

return ObjectIdentifier.getHashCode() + TaskIdentifier.getHashCode()
or other can be - a^3 + b^2 (where a and b are hashes of object identifier and task identifier respectively)
What would be best strategy, any suggestions

My task doesnt involve any IO, and as of now I am using one thread for each task. 
So my current design is ok, or should I try to optimize it based on num of processors. (have fixed num of threads )

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Hello, My my ListOfObjects are series of message which I am recv from external program (via a blockingcollection). And after completing n number of messages, or recv a condition, I have to stop processing the message, take care of that condition, and then resume the processing (continue with the blocking collection loop). I am unable understand how can I implement the above with messages coming from blocking collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a [Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720(v=vs.110).aspx) on one of the lists, and a regular foreach on the other list, for example:

```
Parallel.ForEach (myListOfObjects, currentObject =>
{
    foreach(var task in myListOfTasks)
    {
        task.DoSomething(currentObject);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I must say that I really like Rufus L's answer. You have to be smart about the things you parallelise and not over-encumber your implementation with excessive thread synchronisation and memory-intensive constructs - those things diminish the benefit of parallelisation. Given the large size of the item pool and the CPU-bound nature of the work, `Parallel.ForEach` with a sequential inner loop should provide very reasonable performance while keeping the implementation dead simple. It's a win.

Having said that, I have a pretty trivial LINQ-based tweak to Rufus' answer which addresses your other requirement (which is ***for the same object, for a given task, it should be executed in series***). The solution works provided that the following assumptions hold:

- The order in which the tasks are executed is not significant.
- The work to be performed (all combinations of *task* x *object*) is known in advance and cannot change.
- *(Sorry for stating the obvious)* The work which you want to parallelise *can* be parallelised - i.e. there are no shared resources / side-effects are completely isolated.

With those assumptions in mind, consider the following:

```
// Cartesian product of the two sets (*objects* and *tasks*).
var workItems = objects.SelectMany(
    o => tasks.Select(t => new { Object = o, Task = t })
);

// Group *work items* and materialise *work item groups*.
var workItemGroups = workItems
    .GroupBy(i => i, (key, items) => items.ToArray())
    .ToArray();

Parallel.ForEach(workItemGroups, workItemGroup =>
{
    // Execute non-unique *task* x *object*
    // combinations sequentially.
    foreach (var workItem in workItemGroup)
    {
        workItem.Task.Execute(workItem.Object);
    }
});
```

Note that I am not limiting the degree of parallelism in `Parallel.ForEach`. Since all work is CPU-bound, it will work out the best number of threads on its own.